# How to add TAGs for Network interface of a private endpoint azure with Terraform?

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I need to add tags to a Network interface of a private endpoint (for example PE for KV) azure with Terraform ?

Comment: Is this question about generic resource tagging or NSG/VNet service tags?

Answer (score 0):

Same way you define a tag on any resource, with a tags component.

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "main_rg" {
  name     = "E1-PROD-DataLake-rg"
  location = "East US"

  tags = {
    source = "terraform"
  }
}
```